# Spring data redis with kotlin breaks in version 2.3.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

After migrating Spring Boot from 2.3.0 to 2.3.2.RELEASE, my @RedisHash code is broken.

```
@RedisHash(value = "OtpCache", timeToLive = 5 * 60)
data class OtpCache(@Id val mobile: String,
                        val otp: String)


interface OtpCacheRepository : CrudRepository<OtpCache, String>

val optional = otpCacheRepository.findById("unknown")
println("optional = " + optional.isPresent)
```

When I try to find a instance of OtpCache with unknown identifier using `findById`, instead of getting a Optional.empty(), i see an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.demo.OtpCache.<init>, parameter mobile
at com.example.demo.OtpCache.<init>(DemoApplication.kt) ~[main/:na]
at com.example.demo.OtpCache_Instantiator_humu2e.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[main/:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:238) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
```

This code was working perfect in Spring Boot `2.3.0.RELEASE`

I am using Kotlin data class for creating POJO in my codebase.

Here is link to sample repository

https://github.com/cancerian0684/bug-redishash-springboot

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-1191